# Submitting data without clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, html, struts2

I am working on a project where a user gets some photos to select from. Now i want it to be such that he can directly click the photo and select it without need of any sort of submit button. An object corresponding to  image is sent. How do i do this. Also i am doing it in struts2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<input type="image" />
```

instead of
     tag.
when rendering the images on browser
because,     `<input type="image" />` acts as a submit button in a form.

Comment: As an alternative you can emded the <img/> in a acnhor element <a/> and then handle the onclick event of the anchor element to submit the form.